# Can't deselect bounties in new navigation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-nav

As soon as you click on bounties there doesn't seem to be a way to deselect them. Clicking show all doesn't remove the bounties selection.

Go here : https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=needanswer&tags=git

Then click on bounties in the top right. Then under Show change it to one of the other selections. Still seeing a list of only bountied questions.

Comment: Just to be clear the url posted isn't a direct repro of the issue but a starting point, it appears to be session related.

Comment: Oh, never mind.

Comment: @PythonMaster edited for clarity now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are sorting by "ending". Questions with bounties have a positive ending and appear first. Questions without bounties are second.

Comment: Except there were only two questions in the list so nothing to do with sorting. It wasn't showing bountied questions first then non bounty questions, it was shown only the former.

Comment: Not sure: it doesn't do that for me. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Likewise, it seems rather odd.

Comment: It is this. Perhaps more of a usability thing in the sense that there was no (immediately) obvious means to deselect the bounty, as sorting by ending wasn't a direct action but an indirect one as a result of clicking on bounties. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Really then I think this ought to be rephrased as a suggestion to change the sort option when changing Show to something other than bounties?